# E: Type 'License' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list E: The list of sources could not be read

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, updates

When I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get this error:

```
E: Type 'License' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I tried to enter that location and remove line 1.
Then I reran the command.

#### Result

The same error is showing for the following line and it remains like that!
Do I have to delete all the lines? What should I do?

> Edit

Also when i run this command

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
```

**output**

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe main multiverse restricted

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports universe main multiverse restricted

# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main

License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html> This is free software: you are free
to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by law.

Home: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.UZ7VSJpZcy
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2

Syntax: gpg [options] [files]
Sign, check, encrypt or decrypt
Default operation depends on the input data

Commands:
 
 -s, --sign                  make a signature
     --clear-sign            make a clear text signature
 -b, --detach-sign           make a detached signature
 -e, --encrypt               encrypt data
 -c, --symmetric             encryption only with symmetric cipher
 -d, --decrypt               decrypt data (default)
     --verify                verify a signature
 -k, --list-keys             list keys
     --list-signatures       list keys and signatures
     --check-signatures      list and check key signatures
     --fingerprint           list keys and fingerprints
 -K, --list-secret-keys      list secret keys
     --generate-key          generate a new key pair
     --quick-generate-key    quickly generate a new key pair
     --quick-add-uid         quickly add a new user-id
     --quick-revoke-uid      quickly revoke a user-id
     --quick-set-expire      quickly set a new expiration date
     --full-generate-key     full featured key pair generation
     --generate-revocation   generate a revocation certificate
     --delete-keys           remove keys from the public keyring
     --delete-secret-keys    remove keys from the secret keyring
     --quick-sign-key        quickly sign a key
     --quick-lsign-key       quickly sign a key locally
     --sign-key              sign a key
     --lsign-key             sign a key locally
     --edit-key              sign or edit a key
     --change-passphrase     change a passphrase
     --export                export keys
     --send-keys             export keys to a keyserver
     --receive-keys          import keys from a keyserver
     --search-keys           search for keys on a keyserver
     --refresh-keys          update all keys from a keyserver
     --import                import/merge keys
     --card-status           print the card status
     --edit-card             change data on a card
     --change-pin            change a card's PIN
     --update-trustdb        update the trust database
     --print-md              print message digests
     --server                run in server mode
     --tofu-policy VALUE     set the TOFU policy for a key

Options:
 
 -a, --armor                 create ascii armored output
 -r, --recipient USER-ID     encrypt for USER-ID
 -u, --local-user USER-ID    use USER-ID to sign or decrypt
 -z N                        set compress level to N (0 disables)
     --textmode              use canonical text mode
 -o, --output FILE           write output to FILE
 -v, --verbose               verbose
 -n, --dry-run               do not make any changes
 -i, --interactive           prompt before overwriting
     --openpgp               use strict OpenPGP behavior

(See the man page for a complete listing of all commands and options)

Examples:

 -se -r Bob [file]          sign and encrypt for user Bob
 --clear-sign [file]        make a clear text signature
 --detach-sign [file]       make a detached signature
 --list-keys [names]        show keys
 --fingerprint [names]      show fingerprints

Please report bugs to <https://bugs.gnupg.org>.
OK
```

Comment: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list ` please, edit your question for output.

Comment: Correct the lines that are in error.  We cannot see it, but yes it looks like you have corrupted that file (that directory is empty on install so it's been added by a user later) and it's of little use to you currently, but someone added it for some reason....

Comment: I saw sollutions in that topic but it didn't fix my problem.
Actually, after removing the specific line i get this error:

'E: Malformed line 14 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.'

Comment: `lsb_release -rc` If your System ist really precise. Install a supportet release.

Comment: @nobody
**output**
'Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
'

Answer (score 1):

Fine `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list`

Compare your `/etc/apt/sources.list`  with mine

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
```

Try `sudo apt update`. If apt is complaining about other errors erase the files under folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`